# How to integrate sencha touch plus phone gap in android

Tags: cordova

I have developed an application using sencha touch .This application containg 5 tabs which performs different operations . In that 5 tabs one tab functionality is it conatins some buttons like (Camera , Capture) now when user clicks on that camera button i need to capture a photo and i need to display that photo to the user.This functionality i have a acheived using phone gap.But i don't know how to integrate this code in sencha .

Answer (score 1):

Though it can be done using PhoneGap, it can also be done using Sencha Touch's Camera feature.

- PhoneGap Camera API

  ```
   var imageView = Ext.create('Ext.Img', {
         src:'',
         ....
   });
   ....
   ....

   // PhoneGap Camera API to capture image ..

   navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50 });

   function onSuccess(imageData) {
        imageView.setSrc("data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData);
   }

   function onFail(message) {
        alert('Failed because: ' + message);
   }
  ```

  - Using Sencha Touch Camera feature

    ```
    var imageView = Ext.create('Ext.image',{
       src:'',
       ....
       ....
    });

    Ext.device.Camera.capture({
       success: function(image) {
           imageView.setSrc(image);
       },
       quality: 75,
       width: 200,
       height: 200,
       destination: 'data'
    });
    ```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But my need is not only camera , i need to access all the features of android like compass,geolocation,event handling ,...etc. for that i need to use phone gap

Comment: The Sencha touch camera feature doesnt work for me. It says 'device' is undefined. Any help? @user1017717

Comment: to use Ext.device you have to use the Sencha native packager.  If you are not you have to use the PhoneGap method.  For things other than the Camera see the PhoneGap API.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using sencha touch2.3 and sencha cmd 4.* and after build the application follow the steps.

step1: go to app folder and run from your cmd prompt "sencha cordova init" or "sencha phonegap init"

step2.next go to cordova/phonegap folder from your cmd then run following command
"cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-camera.git"

step3: next run the "cordova plugin ls" to see the list of plugins installed for your app.

step4: then do the requires['Ext.device.Camera'] in your app.js or in your controller file requires

now you can use the camera seamlessly.. try now!!!!!!!!